# Converting Decimal into Time

Tags: reporting

we have a report that is giving us the time as 13.95 when we figure out the average.

We would want it to list as 13:55

How would we do that in a report formula field?

Comment: 0.95 of an hour is 57 minutes not 55 minutes. Do you know what the maths would be to do the conversion you mention (not SF specific formula language just standard maths)?

Comment: I was just giving a rough example, the formula I'm using now is converting seconds:

LiveChatTranscript.ChatDuration:AVG/60

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
LEFT(TEXT(Number_Test__c), FIND('.', TEXT(Number_Test__c)) - 1) + ':' + TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(Number_Test__c), FIND('.', TEXT(Number_Test__c)) - 1)) * 0.60)
```

Swap Number_Test__c for your decimal field :)

**UPDATE**

Sorry just realised you said report formula field - I don't know about that but if you create a regular formula field and use the above formula then you should get what you need.

Comment: Yeah, it's telling me:  Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number).

I think this means I have to put a custom field on the live agent object to get this - which I don't know is possible.  I wonder how other service orgs are doing this.

Comment: Ah yeah, the report formula field has to be of type number, percent or currency. That's annoying. You could create 2 columns, one called hours and one called minutes... bit of a bodge though. I'll keep thinking :)